# Can you ship a PouchDB DB inside app already sync'd?

Tags: cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

I will be creating a hybrid app (i.e. phonegap/cordova or similar) that will use PouchDB to sync a read-only database from a hosted CouchDB instance.

Easiest way to do this is the app ships "empty" and upon first run it needs to pull down all docs from the server before it can then be used.

Preferred way from a user perspective is that I can somehow ship it "pre-replicated" so that it could work immediately after installation (albeit with potentially out of date data) or even if online then it only needs to sync documents which have changed on the server since the app was shipped. Is this feasible?

I understand that the difference in download total for a user is pretty negligible (i.e. they need to download the data one way or another), but I feel users have a larger tolerance for large app sizes versus apps that require them to wait minutes the first time they run them. Also, it's possible people install apps but don't try it until a later point when they are offline or with cellular data instead of wifi (this is a distinct possibility due to the type of app it will be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use the [pouchdb-dump](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli) CLI to dump your database to a file, and then load it using [pouchdb-load](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load).